# "Redirect URI mismatch" error in live server after authenticating user - Google Calendar API + php

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

Im working with Google calendar API (PHP). Everything works perfect in the test server(different server). But when i moved the updates to live, im getting the response for the following code :

```
$accessToken = $google_client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
print_r($accessToken);
```

*Shows the below output :*

```
Array
(
    [error] => redirect_uri_mismatch
    [error_description] => Bad Request
)
```

Every piece of information is correct and verified twice, the redirectURIs provided in the google console, redirectURIs in the json file.
The application authenticates user successfully and redirects to the specified redirect URI, then shows the above error. Does anyone faced such a problem ?

The live application is under a sub-domain like : **abc.def.example.com**

So i provided the redirect URI as

```
http://abc.def.example.com/en/add_to_google_calendar_auth
```

The test server doesnt have a subdomain, So the redirect URI that i used was :

```
http://mydemoserver.com/en/add_to_google_calendar_auth
```

No other significant changes.Both of these URIs has been added to the console & json respectievely. works perfectly the with demo server.

I checked all the questions in SO and other online resources regarding my issue, But none of them solved my issue .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redirect URI is where the response is returned to your application.  It needs to be properly registered in the Google developer console, and the error is indicating that you haven't done that, or haven't done it correctly.

Go to the console for your project and look under API Access. You should see your client ID & secret there, along with a list of redirect URIs. If the URI you want isn't listed, click edit settings and add the URI to the list.

Check the error you are getting there should be a drop down (request details) showing you exactly what the request you are making is and exactly what redirect URI you are sending is.   Remember if you are using a client library they tend to build the redirect uri out of the current file location rather than using the credentials file for ease of use.   *but you havent mentoined if you are doing this with a library so i cant be sure.*

[image]

> Authorized redirect URIs
>   For use with requests from a web server. This is the path in your application that users are redirected to after they have authenticated with Google. The path will be appended with the authorization code for access. **Must have a protocol.** Cannot contain URL fragments or relative paths. Cannot be a public IP address.

Comment: im sure that the redirect URI is exactly the same as the one i specified in the settings. I'm setting the redirectURI : $google_client->setRedirectURI('http://abc.def.example.com/en/add_to_google_calendar_auth '); apart from the json file that i'm using. 
and i was following the quick start example : https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php

Comment: Redirect URI **Must have a protocol.**  have you tried https: //abc.def.example.com/en/add_t‌​o_google_calendar_au‌​th  this sample might help https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Calendar%20API/v3/oauth2callback.php

Comment: @Dalm , The protocol is there , but SO , had parsed the text into a link :)

Comment: what about the space at the end auth ') ?

Comment: That space was a typo.

Comment: After reading "Remember if you are using a client library they tend to build the redirect uri out of the current file location rather than using the credentials file for ease of use", i just commented the $google_client->setRedirectURI() line to see how the redirectURI is working. The redirect URIs are read from the file, and redirected to the demo server. Then i removed the demo server from the console list and kept only live server's URIs. Suddenly the redirection is successful !!. I uncommented the above commented line. working evrything as expected :) . Any idea about the issue ?

Comment: Thank you for the response & obviously your notes in the above answer helped me to do experiments, which eventually solved my problem. So im going to accept your answer.